# Using var to unwrap an optional in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

I've only seen people using `let` to unwrap optionals.
I was wondering if it is a good practice and I could just as well use `var`, or is there something more to it?

What are the pros and cons of using `let` versus `var`?

Comment: As [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) says "If a stored value in your code is not going to change, always declare it as a constant with the `let` keyword. Use variables only for storing values that need to be able to change." As LastMove says, constants make your intent clear, avoid many unintended consequences of something changing when you didn't expect it and apparently allow the compiler greater optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, you should always use `let` when you can, as it allows compiler do some fancy stuff and thus makes your program run faster.

There is **technically** nothing wrong with using var, though.

For further reading, please check out this article:
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/

Answer (score 4):

It like usual;
`let` is for a constant (you will not be able to modify the value).
The good practice is to always use let when you can (when you don't need to modify the value). It is for optimization purpose and for clarity of the code.